# Parse Characterstic.Value to byte integer format

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer, hex, core-bluetooth

I am doing the Core Bluetooth application. I am able to connect the peripheral and read, write value from it.

I need to parse the data which I am receiving through `characteristic.value` to integer format. 
I had the characteristic value as `<011f6d00 00011100 00000000 04050701 05000569 07df0203 020b0d21 02ff33>`.

I have divided the data as per understanding.
Please help me with the sample code for converting the data. As I am new to iOS observed many links but did not find the exact answer

```
  <011f6d00 

11 00  event id       //2 bytes

00    event type      //1 byte

00    No of packets            //1 byte

00 00 record count               //2 byte

04 05 total duration            //2 byte

07       sensitivity            //1 byte

01    recording sensitivity   //1 byte

05    expected seizure duration  //1 byte

00    Not used parameter       //1 byte

05    Expected recorded duration     //1 byte

69    not used parameters     //1 byte

07    snooze duration       //1 byte

df    disable watch help button    //1 byte   

02 03  year        //2 byte

02    date of month     //1 byte

0b    day of week      //1 byte

0d    hour             //1 byte

21    minute            //1 byte

02   second             //1 byte

ff33>    crc          //2 byte
```

Comment: Yes peripheral characteristics is in  binary format. You need to convert it in standard UTF8 String format.

Comment: please help with the sample code .And i need to convert the data in the integer not as an string format

Comment: First edit your question with what-ever you do code so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSData *initialData = [yourCharacteristic value];
```

A way to parse your data is to use `subdataWithRange:` method of `NSData`.

Example:

```
NSData *startOfFrameData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
NSLog(@"StartOfFrameData: %@", startOfFrameData);
NSData *eventIDData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 2)];
NSLog(@"eventIDData: %@", eventIDData);
```

etc.

Output:

```
>StartOfFrame: <011f6d00>
>eventIDData: <0001>
```

Note that I may have reversed the order of `eventIDData` which range could be `(6,2)` (instead of `(4,2)`), but you'll get the whole idea.

Then, you have to "understand" the meaning of the data and find the correct format, example (possible) for `eventIDData`:

```
UInt16 eventID;
[eventIDData getBytes:&eventID length:sizeof(eventID)];
NSLog(@"eventID: %d", eventID);
```

And so on...

If you want to "play" with it without reading again and again the characteristic value each time (which means also connect, etc.), here is a method you can use:

```
-(NSData *)dataWithStringHex:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *cleanString;
    cleanString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    cleanString = [cleanString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    cleanString = [cleanString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSInteger length = [cleanString length];
    uint8_t buffer[length/2];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < length; i+=2)
    {
        unsigned result = 0;
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)]];
        [scanner scanHexInt:&result];
        buffer[i/2] = result;
    }
    return  [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:&buffer length:length/2];
}
```

Example use:

```
NSData *initialData = [self dataWithStringHex:@"<011f6d00 00011100 00000000 04050701 05000569 07df0203 020b0d21 02ff33>"];
```

That way, you can try parsing your data on an other example/project/beta test code.

Comment: Thanks boss looking for exact one