# CoreBluetooth discover pheriperal advertisementData format

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I'm using CoreBluetooth to discover a BLE device.
In

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
 didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
     advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                  RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

I receive `advertisementData` dictionary

```
{
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = "Gate_02";
    kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <00ff0102 0303>;
}
```

If I try to read `advertisementData[@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"]` class I obtain `_NSInlineData`. How can I convert to `NSString` or `NSData` object ?

Comment: `NSData *mftData = advertisementData[@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];` doesn't work?

Comment: Nope... If I convert NSData into NSString I obtain null string

Comment: What logs `mftData` (from my example)? What do you want to do with the `NSString`? What should look like the `NSString`?

Comment: I have to split the string and convert hex number into decimal. But this isn't the core of the question. My question is how decode `_NSInlineData`

Comment: Why going to `NSData` to `NSString`? You may want to use `subdataWithRange:`, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292784/parse-characterstic-value-to-byte-integer-format/28295543#28295543

Comment: what is the format that the data are in the advertising packet? The data might not represent a string..

Comment: Fry did you have any success? Attempting something similar - seems difficult just to get a vendor id.

Answer (score 2):

`NSInlineData` *is* `NSData`. More specifically, it is a (private) subclass of `NSData` - it is a common pattern in Cocoa, called [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).

So you can use all the methods of `NSData` on an instance of `NSInlineData`.

I'm not sure what do you mean by "converting NSData to NSString". The value of `kCBAdvDataManufacturerData` does not look like `NSString` (as its first byte is `0x00`, which is usually used to terminate the string).

If you want to convert the hexadecimal data to decimal, there's no need to convert it to `NSString` first. You can iterate on `NSData` byte-by-byte, like this:

```
  for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    Byte byte = 0;
    [data getBytes:&byte range:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    //do something with byte
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use objectForKey to access the different objects in the advertisement data

```
//Pull the localName and manufacturing Data out of the advertising data
NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
NSData   *mfgData   = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey];
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - OP knows how to access the contents of the dictionary, but he doesn't know what to do with them.