# Converting NSData as string to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

If I have NSData converted as string,like this

```
NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", hashedData];
```

How can I convert someString back to hashedData?

For example in the following code

```
NSString *string = @"This is a string";

NSData *data1 = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"data: %@",data1);
NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data1];
NSData* data2 = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data2: %@",data2);
```

I get the following output

```
data1: <54686973 20697320 61207374 72696e67>
data2: <3c353436 38363937 33203230 36393733 32302036 31323037 33373420 37323639 36653637 3e>
```

What I want is that data2 should be same as data1. I mean converting the dataString back to the original hashedData.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert an NSString value to NSData?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901357/how-do-i-convert-an-nsstring-value-to-nsdata)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Please view the update.

Comment: `dataString` is clearly no the same as `string`. Printing its description is not the same. You are looking for the method there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28295543/1801544 ? (Can't find the original one, I post mine "version").

Comment: see my answer as you want may help you..

Comment: Why in the world would you double encode the string?

Comment: @Larme thank you very much. Your post solved the problem

Comment: @I'L'I Actually I am sending data to server as NSData and it is returning me that binary data as string. Therefore I have to convert it back to NSData.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code like this :

```
NSString *string = @"This is a string";   
NSData *data1 = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data: %@",data1);
NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data1 bytes]];
NSData* data2 = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data2: %@",data2);
```

**Output:**

> Demoapp[1024:22267] data: <54686973 20697320 61207374 72696e67>
>   2015-09-04 12:52:10.104 Demoapp[1024:22267] data2: <54686973 20697320
>   61207374 72696e67 02>

Comment: This does not solve the issue. Please view the update.

Comment: I tested this code and dataString becomes nil. My problem has been solved by http://stackoverflow.com/a/28295543/1801544. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You cant assign `NSData` to `NSString` directly, you have to convert the NSData to NSString like this

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Check updated code

```
NSString *string = @"This is a string";

NSData *data1 = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"data: %@",data1);
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData* data2 = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data2: %@",data2);
```

Now both the `NSData` are same

Answer (score 0):

Convert data to string :-

```
 NSData *data ;
 NSLog(@"data is :%@",data);
 NSString *strr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"Responce is : %@",strr);
```

Now convert string to data :-

```
 NSData *dataa = [strr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"data is :%@",dataa);


 2015-09-04 12:43:54.502 TokenPic[2003:60b] data is :<7b227375 63636573 73223a22 31222c22 706f7374 73223a22 4576656e 74204372 65617465 64205375 63636573 7366756c 6c792e22 7d>
 2015-09-04 12:44:01.165 TokenPic[2003:60b] Responce is : {"success":"1","posts":"Event Created Successfully."}
 2015-09-04 12:44:02.801 TokenPic[2003:60b] data is :<7b227375 63636573 73223a22 31222c22 706f7374 73223a22 4576656e 74204372 65617465 64205375 63636573 7366756c 6c792e22 7d>
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting `NSData` to `NSString` in Swift 1.2:

```
let stringFromData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Converting `NSString` to `NSData` in Swift 1.2:

```
let dataFromString = myString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
```